# ngx-toastr - Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr, angular2-toaster

I have installed ngx-toastr and imported in app.module.ts but getting this error while compiling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzrQ6.png)...is it because i have set the properties of toaster in service file which I created like below?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coKP0.png)

I tried adding @import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css'; in styles.css still no effect. Does anyone know what might be the reason for this error and how to fix it

Comment: You should provide some more input - how you import he module in app.module.ts, version of angular and toastr module. It could be some incompatible versions. Normally I add config for toastr in app.module.ts: ToastrModule.forRoot({
   timeOut: 0,
   tapToDismiss: false,
   closeButton: true,
   extendedTimeOut: 0,
   enableHtml: true
  }),

Comment: I get the same error with Angular 14.

Comment: @cjs1978 same for me with Angular 14. Downgrading to 15.0.2 works

Answer (score 12):

you should try to uninstall your current version ngx-toastr, then try to install another version, I installed version 15.2.0 `npm install --save ngx-toastr@15.2.0`, that works for me.

Comment: Good answer, you should edit it though to be more readable. Put the command in code brackets for easy copy-paste. `npm install --save ngx-toastr@15.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

This version worked for me "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",

Comment: downgrading to 15.2.0 worked for me